# Why initialized variable before usage is faster than uninitialized variable

Tags: c, linux

For example, variable `i` in the `C` code below:

t03a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=0;
    int b=1;
    int i=0;//When a variable is declared,the variable is initialised
    for(i=0;i<1000000000;++i);
    return 0;
}
```

t03b.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=0;
    int b=1;
    int i;    // not initialized
    for(i=0;i<1000000000;++i);
    return 0;
}
```

The result (test by linux time):

```
t03a:
real    0m0.527s
user    0m0.250s
sys     0m0.004s

t03b:
real    0m2.499s
user    0m2.431s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Of course, I ran the test many times. Why is t03a faster than t03b?

Comment: Run the test a couple of hundred thousand (or even a couple of million) times, and get the average time. Just running once or twice (especially just a few times just after each other) will not give you reliable results on a multi-tasking system.

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler?

Comment: Also, please don't post code-snippets with line numbers, it makes it harder to copy the code for testing locally.

Comment: modern machines do a billion instructions per second. are you trying to measure a difference of *one* instruction? not too wise...

Comment: That loop has no side effects, I'm surprised it even seems to generate executable code in `t03b.c`. You didn't explicitly disable trivial optimizations (the ones the compiler always does anyway), did you?

Comment: Look at the assembly output (gcc -S ...).

Comment: I'd bet that you have additional zero in the second benchmark and the loop runs 10 more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run the test for a couple of times. Below is a pretty average result of both programs:

```
[xxx@arch-desktop: ~/]$ time ./t03a
real    0m2.819s
user    0m2.817s
sys     0m0.000s
[xxx@arch-desktop: ~/]$ time ./t03b
real    0m2.815s
user    0m2.813s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -o t03a t03a.c`. Maybe you can try using the optimizing parameter(i.e. `-O3`).

I don't think there should be any difference if it's compiled in the right way. Declaring and defining it directly shouldn't be any different from defining it later.

Comment: Profiling unoptimised code is essentially meaningless...

Comment: True. I don't think there should be _any_ difference when both snippets are compiled with optimization enabled. Profiling would be valuable when knowing the produced assembly code though.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (an Intel x86 with gcc), both routines compile to almost identical assembly.  The only difference is that 0 is put on the stack twice in the second example.  I can't imagine this taking much time.

Compiled with `-O1` I get *identical* (if not especially useful) code for both examples.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the assembly code from t03a.c is the same than t03b.c, but with one more instruction, so I guess you were doing something else and the scheduler gave another process a little more execution time or maybe it was for another reason, however te execution time aren't so great and the difference is not much to conclude something, the difference is only one instruction (you have to think that you are doing 1000000000+ instructions in less than 3 seconds, so 1 instruction won't make a difference that will be perceived).

```
.file   "t03b.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $999999999, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

---

```
    .file   "t03b.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $999999999, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize is a useful practice for the style of the code and for avoiding some null and logic errors.
So this is the main scope of initialization.

But for my tests the difference of performance for t03a.c and t03b.c on Linux architecture have not significant difference.

Be carefully to analyse results because also temperature of CPU, mainboard and ect ...influence the time  of compilation (you need to the take an relative and absolute error if you want to demonstrate your assertion when the difference is so little).